# Sending email in Outlook to one person that shows multiple recipients?

Tags: vbscript, outlook

I'm using VBScript and CDO to send emails from a custom form in Outlook. Basically:

```
Sub MySendButton_Click()
    Set objEmail = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
    objEmail.To = "a@a.a; b@b.b; c@c.c"
    objEmail.HTMLBody = "<b>hi!</b>"
    objEmail.Send()
End Sub
```

Is it possible to send an email to only "a@a.a" but show all three recipients in the To field on that person's copy? I need this functionality so that the end user can Reply To All, but the other recipients don't need to receive this particular email.

Answer (score 0):

I think [`ReplyTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms527554.aspx) is what you need:

```
objEmail.To = "a@a.a"
objEmail.ReplyTo = "a@a.a; b@b.b; c@c.c"
```

Comment: It actually looks like `ReplyAll` is exactly what I was looking for. What is the correct syntax to invoke `ReplyAll`?